# How to resize quickly a imgur image?

Tags: url, imgur

Is there any way to resize an [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) image using the query string when I use it on a forum?

This image is too big for some forum and it ruins the pagination.

[image: incredibly huge image in a forum]

Comment: the image somehow really freak me out...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can specify the small version of the image by appending `s` to its base URL.

For example, the URL of your original image is
`https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brjd7.jpg`.
By adding `s` this becomes `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brjd7s.jpg`:

[[image: smaller image version]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brjd7s.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brjd7s.jpg)

Some images may have an ultra-small version of the image, accessed by
adding `ss`, thus making it `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brjd7ss.jpg`,
but your image does not have one.

Here is the list of all the modifiers for dimensions
(not all are always available) :

```
s =   90×  90 = Small Square (as seen in the example above)
b =  160× 160 = Big Square 
t =  160× 160 = Small Thumbnail 
m =  320× 320 = Medium Thumbnail 
l =  640× 640 = Large Thumbnail
h = 1024×1024 = Huge Thumbnail
```

Comment: the answer hints at that, but it is the pixel area and proportions of the original image that determine which of the modifiers will be available. A very narrow but tall rectangular pic, for instance, might not produce a "s" version even if the original is high quality. Or it might produce urls where "m" (medium) is the same as "l" (large).  The `<img src="x" width="N" />` method (described [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1238701/525084)) can produce a custom resize for these edge cases, but it's slower than just adding a modifier to a URL.

Answer (score 5):

It may depend on the type of encoding the forum uses.

On Stack Exchange you can use the line `<img src="[url]" width="[nnn]">` to specify the size quite precisely.

eg
`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Brjd7.jpg" width="123">`

[image]

The advantage of this method is the full size image is available to anyone who needs to see it, by right-clicking & opening in a new tab.

Comment: This still _loads_ the full size image

Comment: It loads the full image drawn at the dimensions specified. For about 18 months from the end of 2017, this was the **only** way you could do it, the `s,t,m,l` etc mechanism was broken.